# How to check if javascript (js file) has been loaded or not loaded using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using php to check is a javascript file has been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976277/using-php-to-check-is-a-javascript-file-has-been-loaded)

Is it possible to check if the js file is already loaded in a page using PHP? Because I have some block on my page that needs the js file. So if the js file is not loaded then don't load this block.

It's something like this:

if js file is not loaded then
    don't execute this php script
else
    execute this php script

Comment: go to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976277/using-php-to-check-is-a-javascript-file-has-been-loaded

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

PHP sends an HTML document to the client **then** the client then handles the HTML and makes HTTP requests for any JavaScript files.

Redesign the block that depends on the JS to make use of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Writing your JS so it is [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) will help with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. If it's not possible, is there a way to run javascript even there are so many plugin like in firefox to prevent javascript from running? Is ajax the answer for this? Can ajax run even there are plugin that preven javascript from running on a page?

Comment: No. User preferences to block JavaScript would be pointless if pages could override them. Ajax is a buzzword that means, more or less, "Using JavaScript to make HTTP requests" so you can't use it without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of successful JS files in cookies or pass the details to future PHP files. Otherwise, PHP is server side and JS is client side.

Comment: thank you. you give me a clue. i created a cookie then check it using php if it was loaded. if not meaning the js script is not loaded too.